# Can we make Bundle Css and Javascript in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

How do I use a Bundle in Laravel like Asp MVC?

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
  {
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/js/AdminLTE/app.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/js/iframePopUp.js",
            "~/Scripts/js/sweetalert/sweet-alert.min.js"
       ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.1 comes with Elixir http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir. Which can do this for you see sections

Combine Stylesheets

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "normalize.css",
        "main.css"
    ]);
});
```

and Combine Scripts

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        "jquery.js",
        "app.js"
    ]); 
});
```

Here is a pretty neat free laracast video that can help you with this too ->

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/10